# Access SQL Group by with condition

Tags: sql, ms-access, switch-statement

I'm using MS Access for the following task (due to office restrictions). I'm quite new to SQL.

I have the following table:
[image]

I want to select all stores grouped by street, zip and place. But i only want to group them, if the SquareSum (after Group by) is < 1000. Rue de gare 2 should be grouped, while Bahnhofstrasse 23 should be seperate lines.

So far as i know  MS Access doesn't allow a case statement. So my query looks like this:

```
SELECT 
Street,
ZIP,
Place,
Sum(Square) AS SumSquare, 
FROM Table1 
SWITCH (SumSquare > 1000, GROUP BY (Street, ZIP, Place))
```

I also tried:

```
GROUP BY
SWITCH (SumSquare > 1000, (Street, ZIP, Place))
```

But it keeps telling me i have a syntax error. Could someone please help me?

Comment: Please put your code in the code block.

Comment: Show us some sample table data (as formatted text, not images), and also the expected result.

Comment: [How to ask a good SQL question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/3820271).

Comment: Thanks for the advices and sorry for the bad layout. - next time will be better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Access, I would do this with several queries.

This would be easier to do if you had an id on the rows (such as an autonumber).

First query identifies the streets that should be summed.

query: `SumTheseStreets`

```
SELECT 
Street,
ZIP,
Place,
Sum(Square) AS SumSquare 
FROM Table1 
GROUP BY Street, ZIP, Place
HAVING sum(Square) < 1000
```

Note the `HAVING` which is a bit like a `WHERE` clause that's applied outside of the `GROUP BY` or `SUM`

Second query identifies the other rows (notes on this one below):

query: `StreetsNotSummed`

```
SELECT 
Street,
ZIP,
Place,
Square AS SumSquare 
FROM Table1
LEFT JOIN SumTheseStreets ON Table1.Street = SumTheseStreets.Street AND Table1.ZIP = SUmTheseStreets.ZIP AND Table1.Place = SumTheseStreets.Place
WHERE SumTheseStreets.Street IS NULL;
```

A couple of notes:

- I've called the field SumSquare because I want it to be the same name as the SumSquare field in the first query
- It uses the first query as one of the input "tables"
- This uses a LEFT JOIN which means "give me all of the rows in the first table (table1) and if any rows in the second table (SumTheseStreets) match, put those in as well.
- but then it filters out the rows that DO match.

So this query only lists the streets that you want NOT summed.

So now you need a third query.
This simply includes all of the rows in both of those queries.
I'm not too sure on the Access syntax on this one, but there's a union query wizard if this isn't right.

Query: `TheAnswerRequired`

```
SELECT 
Street,
ZIP,
Place,
SumSquare
FROM SumTheseStreets

UNION

SELECT 
Street,
ZIP,
Place,
SumSquare
FROM StreetsNotSummed
```

(it might need to be `UNION ALL`)

Good luck.

Comment: This worked for me - thank you very much! I'm jst wondering: Do you recommend the same approach when not using Access?

Comment: When not using Access, I'd _probably_ do something similar to  @Gordon-Linoff 's answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT ts.*
FROM (SELECT Street, Zip, Place, SUM(Square) as SumSquare
      FROM Table1
      GROUP BY Street, Zip, Place
     ) as ts
WHERE ts.SumSquare < 1000
UNION ALL
SELECT t1.*
FROM Table1 as t1 INNER JOIN
     (SELECT Street, Zip, Place, SUM(Square) as SumSquare
      FROM Table1
      GROUP BY Street, Zip, Place
     ) as ts
     ON t1.Street = ts.Street AND t1.Zip = ts.Zip and t1.Place = ts.Place
WHERE ts.SumSquare >= 1000
```